# How to focus bootstrap datetime picker?

Tags: jquery, css

I am using Bootstrap datetime picker (bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js) part of my code.

Using class="modal fade" under the DIV tag, which will open a first popup , now in the first popup there is a datetime picker, on click of picker it is showing the second popup for time but it is hiding / not focused. I want to move the focus from first popup to second popup. How can i achieve this?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: provide a sample will be great.

Answer (score 0):

The bootstrap `datetimepicker` control has a span tag which displays the calendar when it get's clicked.To set focus to the control just simulate a trigger event to this span tag.Here's a complete example:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.37/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.css" />
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/momentjs/2.13.0/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.37/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {

        $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker();

        $("#btnSetFocus").focus(function () {
            $('.input-group-addon').trigger("click");
        });

    });
</script>
<input type="button" value="Set Focus" id="btnSetFocus" />
<div class="form-group">
    <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker1'>
        <input type='text' class="form-control" />
        <span class="input-group-addon">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use focus element function to set focus to any element.
try below code once :

```
function safeFocus() {
              $timeout(function () {
                  element[0].focus();
              }, 0);
             }
```